# Is it possible to use sandBox for sharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, sandbox

I wanted to know if it's possible to use a sandBox to test my code in SharePoint online ? This way, I can test my code, and my colleagues can continues to work on sites.

Thank's !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not for any compiled code. I.e. anything that requires a DLL. You can still deploy Sandbox Solutions that are all HTML, CSS and JavaScript (with a few exceptions).

Note that many of the Sandbox Solutions will not work with the "modern UI".